# Can't compilers jump down to find definition of called function?

Tags: c++, function, forward-declaration, function-prototypes

In C++, execution starts from top of main (). Ok, got it. Now look at this:

```
  #include <iostream>
   int main ()
   {
       int x;
       std::cin >> x;
       std::cout << add (x, x);
       return 0;
   }

   int add(int x, int y)
   {
         return x+y;
   }
```

Compiler throws an error when executing this program. If I shift my add () above main () or use a forward declaration, program get compiled without any error. Does that mean that a compiler can't jump down from caller function to find the definition of called function that is defined below the caller. Forgive my english please.

Answer (score 6):

Of course compilers can scan ahead and find the function definition. However, the standards of C (and by extension, C++) have a very long history, dating back to the times when having a second pass over the code being compiled was very expensive due to slow access to files on magnetic disks. Relative shortage of memory has been a factor as well.

This consideration certainly contributed to requiring forward declarations in C, and C++ inherited it. Changing this requirement would introduce a very considerable change into the language, making it much harder to backport new programs to older compilers. It does not mean that it couldn't be done at some later time, but it hasn't been done at the moment.

Comment: Actually, C does not require forward declarations until C99, so you can't really say that C++ inherited the requirement from C. If anything, it's probably the reverse. (C always did have the possibility of forward declarations, but they weren't required. If you replace `cin` and `cout ` with `scanf` and `printf` respectively in this example, it will compile in pre-C99 mode.)

Comment: @celticminstrel I am almost certain that forward declarations were strongly suggested back in the ANSI edition of the standard - at least I remember that compilers used to give warnings for missing forward declaration. C did allow for missing forward declarations, but it made an assumption that the function is `int`, and that all its parameters, if it has any, are `int`. This assumption was crazy by today's standards, but back at the time it was a good stop-gap measure to enable construction of single pass compilers.

Comment: They might've been strongly suggested, but it's still the case that they weren't required.

Answer (score 0):

Practically speaking, you **can** force the compiler to look ahead as a means of keeping your code clean. You do this with a function prototype. In your code, this would look like:

```
#include <iostream>
   int add(int x, int y);

   int main ()
   {
       int x;
       std::cin >> x;
       std::cout << add (x, x);
       return 0;
   }

   int add(int x, int y)
   {
       return x+y;
   }
```

This tells the compiler that a function called add exists, and that it takes two ints as arguments and returns an int. But since it isn't defined, it looks elsewhere in the code.

If you put every function prototype you needed at the top of your source, it could get almost as ugly as putting every function definition at the top of your source, which is why people use header files (.h) to store them, typically.